# How to find out which database instance is used? amazon rds or database in ec2 instance?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a drupal website running in amazon ec2. Can I know which database is it using? I know it is a MySQL database.  I want to know it is using database in amazon ec2 instance or amazon rds database ? If I found out the database server , can I access them through clients like "Emma" or "MySQL WorkBench" ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to find this information, you should be able to access the management console of the AWS account that created this website.
In order to located RDS instance, follow these steps:

1. Login to your AWS management portal at console.aws.amazon.com .
2. Under the "Database" section, find "RDS", go to "Instances".
3. If you have any RDS databases, you will see them in the list, there, you will also be able to see connection details.

In case of EC2, perform the following:

1. Login to your AWS management portal at console.aws.amazon.com .
2. Under the "Compute" section find "EC2", go to "Running Instances".
3. There, you will be able to see several EC2 instances. Some of them should be your application servers, some of them should be your database servers.
4. You can connect to the EC2 instance using the following guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html

Regarding your question about possibility to connect via MySQL workbench. Technically it's possible (You can find connection details in the properties of your RDS instance. In case of EC2, you should connect to the IP of an EC2 instance) , but there is a concern. According to general best practices, database  servers are not available from the outside word so you may have to login to the app server first and go to the database from there.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If plenty of such instances exist, then I guess I can look at the settings.php in drupal to correctly identify which database instance it is using among the available database instances.